# How to sort nested array depending on values in the inner array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, microsoft-graph-api

I have an array of To-Do lists with an array of tasks inside of the array. I now need to sort the array depending on the value of the inner array. I want the array to be sorted by highest priority on the `important` attribute first. Then remove all todos that have a `dueDateTime` **(if it exists)** that are older than today (Because Microsoft Graph API returns all tasks in a separate list of todos, and don't exclude older tasks). todos that don't have a `dueDateTime` should not be removed from the array. The existing values should be sorted by the `dueDateTime` value.

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

This is my **array** with all the tasks that **Microsoft Graph API** returns:

```
    let todos =    [{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7dec6a0-3f91-43e2-8a28-d6de2f238caa')/todo/lists('AQMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OAAALgAAA7JK6Wv8LyFEhk0vxTmAtLMBANEaHwdeaklLnbQ6yUS32Z0AAAIBEgAAAA%3D%3D')/tasks",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbfP5Q==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test12341241241241451",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:20:54.6522448Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-12T06:23:04.4839213Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAAAAESAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfurHAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        },
        "dueDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2021-11-12T23:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbefnQ==\"",
        "importance": "high",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test 1231551515155",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:20:51.5538432Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:14.5876034Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAAAAESAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfurGAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        },
        "dueDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2021-11-10T23:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7dec6a0-3f91-43e2-8a28-d6de2f238caa')/todo/lists('AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OAAuAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzAQDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAAA%3D')/tasks",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeZZg==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test test'",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T06:55:42.8810298Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T07:05:43.9657845Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAFujyNAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeZZA==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test test testtest test testtest test testtest test test",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T06:55:40.2346649Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T07:05:41.8202032Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAFujyMAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeflQ==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "detta är ett test",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T06:55:30.6219299Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:13.9912155Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAFujyLAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeflw==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "Testar filips lista",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:21:52.9503933Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:14.1395668Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfvKlAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7dec6a0-3f91-43e2-8a28-d6de2f238caa')/todo/lists('AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OAAuAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzAQDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5BAAA%3D')/tasks",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbefmQ==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "Detta är ett test i test",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:21:45.376632Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:14.2918996Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5BAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfu66AAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }]
}];
```

**Update:**

I tried the first answers code from @Tom and got the **error**:

> "Uncaught TypeError: item.dueDateTime.dateTime.getTime is not a
> function",

I also tried to use `new Date (item.dueDateTime.dateTime)` to convert it to a valid date format but it did not work..

**Update 2**

I tried the answers updated code and i get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateTime')"

```js
let todos =    [{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7dec6a0-3f91-43e2-8a28-d6de2f238caa')/todo/lists('AQMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OAAALgAAA7JK6Wv8LyFEhk0vxTmAtLMBANEaHwdeaklLnbQ6yUS32Z0AAAIBEgAAAA%3D%3D')/tasks",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbfP5Q==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test12341241241241451",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:20:54.6522448Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-12T06:23:04.4839213Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAAAAESAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfurHAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        },
        "dueDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2021-11-12T23:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbefnQ==\"",
        "importance": "high",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test 1231551515155",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:20:51.5538432Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:14.5876034Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAAAAESAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfurGAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        },
        "dueDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2021-11-10T23:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7dec6a0-3f91-43e2-8a28-d6de2f238caa')/todo/lists('AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OAAuAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzAQDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAAA%3D')/tasks",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeZZg==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test testtest test test'",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T06:55:42.8810298Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T07:05:43.9657845Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAFujyNAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeZZA==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "test test testtest test testtest test testtest test test",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T06:55:40.2346649Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T07:05:41.8202032Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAFujyMAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeflQ==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "detta är ett test",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-11T06:55:30.6219299Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:13.9912155Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAAFujyLAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }, {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbeflw==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "Testar filips lista",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:21:52.9503933Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:14.1395668Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5CAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfvKlAAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('f7dec6a0-3f91-43e2-8a28-d6de2f238caa')/todo/lists('AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OAAuAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzAQDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5BAAA%3D')/tasks",
    "value": [{
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"0RofB15qSUudtDrJRLfZnQAABbefmQ==\"",
        "importance": "normal",
        "isReminderOn": false,
        "status": "notStarted",
        "title": "Detta är ett test i test",
        "createdDateTime": "2021-11-10T09:21:45.376632Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-11-11T09:19:14.2918996Z",
        "id": "AAMkAGU0Yjc1Y2U4LWE3ODYtNGE3YS04ZjVlLTQxYjlmNDZkYWM4OABGAAAAAACySulr-C8hRIZNL8U5gLSzBwDRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfg5BAADRGh8HXmpJS520OslEt9mdAAADfu66AAA=",
        "body": {
            "content": "",
            "contentType": "text"
        }
    }]
}];

let newArray = [];

// flatten the array so we can use Array.sort()
todos.forEach(list => {
  list.value.forEach(item => {
    newArray.push(item);
  })
});

// filter out anything older than 1 day
newArray = newArray.filter((item) => {
  return new Date(item.dueDateTime.dateTime).getTime() + 86400000 < new Date().getTime(); // 8.64 million = 1 day
});

// sort the array
newArray = newArray.sort((a, b) => {
  // convert importance to numbers so we can compare
  const aScore = a.importance === 'high' ? 1 : 0;
  const bScore = b.importance === 'high' ? 1 : 0;
  // sorts by importance. If the importances are equal a-b is 0, so
  // instead we sort by dates, putting the lowest first
  return aScore - bScore || !b.dueDateTime ? 1 : !a.dueDateTime ? -1 : new Date(b.dueDateTime.dateTime).getTime() - new Date(a.dueDateTime.dateTime).getTime();
});
```

Comment: What exactly are the rules for sorting that you want? Sorting so high importance values come first and then sorting by date after?
Generally a combination of [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should make it possible.

Comment: Sort on high importance first, then remove all todos that are older than today's date. After that sort on the due date time for the remaining values in the array. The values that don't have a due date time should not be removed from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably be easier for you to flatten your array first and then run a sort function on it.

```
let newArray = [];

// flatten the array so we can use Array.sort()
todos.forEach((list) => {
  list.forEach((item) => {
    newArray.push(item);
  }
}

// filter out anything older than 1 day
newArray = newArray.filter((item) => {
  return !item.dueDateTime || new Date(item.dueDateTime.dateTime).getTime() + 86400000 < new Date().getTime(); // 8.64 million = 1 day
});

// sort the array
newArray = newArray.sort((a, b) => {
  // convert importance to numbers so we can compare
  const aScore = a.importance === 'high' ? 1 : 0;
  const bScore = b.importance === 'high' ? 1 : 0;
  // sorts by importance. If the importances are equal a-b is 0, so
  // instead we sort by dates, putting the lowest first
  return aScore - bScore || !b.dueDateTime ? 1 : !a.dueDateTime ? -1 : new Date(b.dueDateTime.dateTime).getTime() - new Date(a.dueDateTime.dateTime).getTime();
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but I got this error: "Uncaught TypeError: item.dueDateTime.dateTime.getTime is not a function",

Comment: I just updated the code. You need to convert your date string to a date object using `new Date` before calling `getTime`

Comment: I tried that as you can se in my updated question, but it did not work.

Comment: What are you getting as a result of the new code? "did not work" doesn't really help with debugging

Comment: I updated the answer with just the current code and if you run the code you get the errors from it.

Comment: Ok, so if there's no dueDateTime then should these go before or after those with a due date?

Comment: The ones with no due date should go after the ones with a due date.

Comment: @FilipHuhta How about now? We need to catch the condition that the dueDateTime variable doesn't exist

Comment: Still same error updated code in question:  

Error:{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dateTime')",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 133,
  "colno": 36
}

Comment: Ah ok, the error is inside the filter function. Once again i've updated it.
While I do want to make sure my answer is correct, you know since this is your code you really should be doing some of the debugging effort yourself